How to Reference an Instantiated Object
I'm trying to reference a instantiated object so that I can destroy it if the players mouse hits it
Update:
Wrote new code but still does not destroy and according to the Debug.Log NewPea is null and does not equal anything.
        transform.position = new Vector3(-3.89f, -0.76f, 0f);
        Rot = transform.rotation;
        Pos = transform.position;
        NewPea = Instantiate(peaRB, Pos, Rot).gameObject;
        Rigidbody2D NewPeaRB = NewPea.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        NewPeaRB.AddForce(Vector2.right * 9, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        NewPeaRB.AddForce(Vector2.up * 9, ForceMode2D.Impulse);


    }
}
public void PeaSelfDestroy()
{
    Debug.Log("death");
    Destroy(NewPea);
    Debug.Log(NewPea);
}

_col.GetComponent<PeaScript>().PeaSelfDestroy();


RigidBody is a component attached to an object.  You need to track the GameObject (that you get from Instantiate()) to destroy it.

Component  anything that can be attached to a gameobject has a reference to the gameobject it is attached to.

@Immersive that totally depends on what type peaRB is of .. and I would assume it is a Rigidbody2D ... so OP: simply do Destroy(NewPeaRB.gameObject); ?

@derHugo when I tried that I ran into a Null reference exception

@RunningPath without having a [mcve] including for instance all the types your different variables/fields have it will be quite hard to help here

Use this to get the reference for the GameObject of created component.
GameObject NewPea = Instantiate(peaRB, Pos, Rot).gameObject;


instantiate returns the same type of object that is given to it,
you have two options
1- this one is more sensical usualy
GameObject NewPeaRB=Intantiate(peaRB, Pos, Rot);

//when mouse hits
Destroy(NewPeaRB);

2- but if you are sure your peaRB has a rigidbody2D attached, then do this.
Rigidbody2D NewPeaRB = Instantiate(peaRB, Pos, Rot).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

Destroy(NewPeaRB.gameObject);


instantiate returns the object and not the rigidbody no that's wrong. T Instantiate(T) returns the same type as the given parameter and if it is a Rigidbody2D  - as I would assume from the name peaRB - then Instantiate creates a deep clone GameObject but returns the according Rigidbody2D component reference
